# dc.js exclude the brushed area and highlight rest

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I'm not data-viz expert or d3, I have found plenty of examples to how to build brushing and zoom [for example Mike](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172).

They all have shown how to filter to the brushed area but I want to achieve to reverse of that effect, how?

Can someone through me ideas how to achieve it?

Comment: Hi, please use the dc.js tag for questions about the charting library - dc is quite something else. The brushing and exclusion part I get, but what do you mean by zoom here? Seems like you would not want to zoom because then you wouldn't see the selection / filter.

Comment: Hi @Gordon, You got what I mean. The zoom is what I'm referring to detailed chart (when we select the bottom chart - brush). Henceforth I will tag d3js. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Actually, I'm sorry, but I don't know what you mean. I can tell you how to exclude a brushed region, but I still don't get what you would zoom to in the top chart - the excluded area?

Comment: Hi @Gordon, My bad I wasn't able to explain it better. Could you please suggest me how to exclude the brushed region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why I assumed you meant a bar chart when you linked to an area chart. You can ignore the highlighting section and skip to filtering if you're interested in doing this with line charts. There is no highlighting of line chart, just the brush itself.

#### Highlighting the bars in reverse

This isn't all that hard, but it's somewhat messy because we replace an undocumented function in the chart. Like most things in dc.js, if there isn't an option, you can usually replace the functionality (or add or change stuff once the chart has rendered/drawn).

Here there's a specific, public function which fades the deselected areas. It's called `fadeDeselectedArea`. (Actually it both fades and un-fades when the chart is ordinal, but we'll ignore that part.)

The original function looks like this:

```
_chart.fadeDeselectedArea = function () {
    var bars = _chart.chartBodyG().selectAll('rect.bar');
    var extent = _chart.brush().extent();

    if (_chart.isOrdinal()) {
        if (_chart.hasFilter()) {
            bars.classed(dc.constants.SELECTED_CLASS, function (d) {
                return _chart.hasFilter(d.x);
            });
            bars.classed(dc.constants.DESELECTED_CLASS, function (d) {
                return !_chart.hasFilter(d.x);
            });
        } else {
            bars.classed(dc.constants.SELECTED_CLASS, false);
            bars.classed(dc.constants.DESELECTED_CLASS, false);
        }
    } else {
        if (!_chart.brushIsEmpty(extent)) {
            var start = extent[0];
            var end = extent[1];

            bars.classed(dc.constants.DESELECTED_CLASS, function (d) {
                return d.x < start || d.x >= end;
            });
        } else {
            bars.classed(dc.constants.DESELECTED_CLASS, false);
        }
    }
};
```

[source link](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/e0d55fb1c31739e7c490076880e3b69eb7da17ff/src/bar-chart.js#L199-L227)

We'll ignore the ordinal part because that's only individual selection, not brushed selection. Here is the reverse of the second part:

```
spendHistChart.fadeDeselectedArea = function () {
    var _chart = this;
    var bars = _chart.chartBodyG().selectAll('rect.bar');
    var extent = _chart.brush().extent();

    // only covering the non-ordinal (ranged brush) case here...
    if (!_chart.brushIsEmpty(extent)) {
        var start = extent[0];
        var end = extent[1];

        bars.classed(dc.constants.DESELECTED_CLASS, function (d) {
            return d.x >= start && d.x < end;
        });
    } else {
        bars.classed(dc.constants.DESELECTED_CLASS, false);
    }
};
```

Creating a variable `_chart` is just to keep the code the same as much as possible. You can see that `d.x >= start && d.x < end` is exactly the opposite of `d.x < start || d.x >= end`

#### Reversing the filtering

We'll need to add a `filterHandler` to the chart in order to reverse the filtering. Again, we'll base it off the [default behavior](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#filterHandler__anchor), but here there's a legitimate customization point so we don't have to replace a function, just supply one:

```
spendHistChart.filterHandler(function(dimension, filters) {
    if(filters.length === 0)
        dimension.filter(null);
    else {
        // assume one RangedFilter but apply in reverse
        // this is less efficient than filterRange but it shouldn't
        // matter much unless the data is huge
        var filter = filters[0];
        dimension.filterFunction(function(d) {
            return !filter.isFiltered(d);
        })
    }
});
```

Again, we cut out the cases we don't care about. There is no reason to be general about something that has a specific purpose and it will only cause maintenance problems. The only two cases we care about are *no filter* and *one range filter*.

Here the `RangedFilter` already supplies a filter function, so we can just call it and not (`!`) the result. This will be slightly less efficient than the `filterRange` but crossfilter has no native support for multiple ranges (or the inverse of a range).

That's it! Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/46snsbc2/8/